# More than two rightBarButtonItem on navigation bar

Tags: ios

I would like to have three rightBarButtonItems on navigation bar. **Add,Edit and Delete.**

And I can't make it using Interface Builder.

Does anybody know how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `UINagivationItem` and `rightBarButtonItems`? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array of bar button items to navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems

```
 UIBarButtonItem *searchButton         = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                             target:self
                                             action:@selector(searchItem:)];

UIBarButtonItem *editButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                                         target:self action:@selector(editItem:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:editButton, searchButton, nil];
```